# Xcode: error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, decltype

I've got this error when trying to compile the following code by xcode. It is compiled without problems by Visual Studio on Windows.

```
template <typename OutT, typename MayaArrayT>
void DumpMayaArray(std::vector<OutT>& out, const MayaArrayT& source)
{
    using MayaElementT = decltype(MayaArrayT()[unsigned int()]); // error happens in this line!
    static_assert(std::is_same<MayaElementT, OutT&>::value, "array type mismatch");
```

What this code snippet is supposed to do is to get type of the element of MayaArrayT from return-type of `::operator[]( unsigned int index );` 
Sadly there is no other way to get type of element of MayaArrayT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in decltype is actually a call to `MayaArrayT::operator(unsigned int)`. However, the arguments to `decltype` are not actually evaluated, so what you need to do is *pretend* you are making the call, like this:

```
using MayaElementT = decltype(
        std::declval<MayaArrayT&>()[std::declval<unsigned int>()]
      );
```

Comment: This is right, although I can't quite work out why it was a _syntax_ error?

Comment: Not too sure either. Good question.

Comment: Both clang and gcc errors are a little confusing, though both point to the `unsigned int` and say they expect a type of some sort. Not very helpful.

Comment: Interesting. I suspect it's a bit of an abstraction leak in the diagnostics

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be a reasonable guess.

Comment: Second code snippet doesn't compile on Visual Studio. First one is working. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, that's odd. An VS compiled the code in your question? I'm not sure why actually.

Comment: I sure will however the problem is that using MayaElementT = decltype(MayaArrayT::operator[]); doesn't seem to be working... Does it works on your machine?

Comment: VS didn't compile it yes, and it did compile code in the question.

Comment: @cigen nice. Something must be wrong with Maya types that use... But anyway this is irrelevant to this question. Thank you for your help!

Comment: No worries. Hope you sort out the issue.

Comment: I'm, actually not sure that the `decltype(MayaArrayT::operator[])` one is right, so I removed that from the answer.